# Безумно большая аватарка при просмотре мобильной версии

Tags: дефект, дизайн, мобильная-версия

При просмотре [страницы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=responses&sort=revisions&&&__=1166773510) в мобильной версии сайта отображается безумная и большая аватарка участника [@strangeqargo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208216/strangeqargo):

[image: ужас:)]

Comment: Особая, уличная магия.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian мага видно по гетерохромии

Comment: Или это ванский кот )